# How to create a long array of 4b elements

Tags: java

Long in Java has size `2^63-1`. But if I write a code like this, my IDE says `Incompatible types: required int but found long`.

```
long [] array = new long[4_000_000_000L];
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: I would avoid doing this. Consider using a sparse array or a database instead.

Comment: TL;DR: the size of an array must not exceed the maximum integer value, which is `2^31 - 1 = 2_147_483_647` (In response to the duplicate entry).